# Integrating $ z^{a-1}(z+z^{-1})^{b}$ on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

For $a>b>-1$, I want to evaluate $$\int_{C} z^{a-1} \left(z + z^{-1}\right)^{b} \, dz$$ where $C$ is the right half of the circle $|z|=1$ traversed counterclockwise.

So I closed the contour with the vertical line segment $[-i, i]$ (indented at $z=i$, $z=0$, and $z=-i$).

Under the restriction mentioned above, I get

$\begin{align} \int_{C}z^{a-1}\left( z+z^{-1}\right)^{b} \, dz &= \int_{-1}^{1}(it)^{a-1}\left( it+(it)^{-1}\right)^{b} \, i \, dt \\ &=\int_{-1}^{1}(it)^{a-1}\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{it}\right)^{b} \, i \, dt \\ &= \require{cancel} \cancel{i} \ i^{a-b}\int_{-1}^{1}t^{a-b-1}\left(1-t^{2}\right)^{b} \, dt \\ &=\cancel{i} \left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi(a-b)}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi(a-b)}{2}\right)\right]\int_{-1}^{1}t^{a-b-1}\left(1-t^{2}\right)^{b} \, dt. \end{align}$

But the book says that it should be $$ 2i \sin\left(\frac{\pi(a-b)}{2}\right)\int_{0}^{1}t^{a-b-1}\left(1-t^{2}\right)^{b}\ dt.$$

How do we get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I can explain this...first of all, you made a mistake in the 3rd line, so let's take it form there.  The integral you seek is

$$\begin{align}i^{a-b} \int_{-1}^1 dt \: t^{a-b-1} (1-t^2)^b &= e^{i \pi (a-b)/2} \left [ \underbrace{\int_{-1}^0 dt \: t^{a-b-1} (1-t^2)^b}_{t=u e^{-i \pi}} + \int_{0}^1 dt \: t^{a-b-1} (1-t^2)^b \right ]\\ &= e^{i \pi (a-b)/2} \left ( e^{-i \pi (a-b-1)}+1\right ) \int_{0}^1 dt \: t^{a-b-1} (1-t^2)^b \\ &= \left ( -e^{-i \pi (a-b)/2}+ e^{i \pi (a-b)/2}\right ) \int_{0}^1 dt \: t^{a-b-1} (1-t^2)^b\end{align}$$

which brings you to your result.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I actually made the substitution but forgot to replace $-1$ with $e^{i \pi}$. That's so strange that they're equivalent.

Comment: It's a crucial fact to know when doing contour integration in the vicinity of a branch point.

Comment: So it has to be $e^{-i \pi}$ and not $e^{i \pi}$ because of the branch point at zero?

Comment: Yes, that's right.